# why gesture detector doesn't work on tapping this container?

Tags: flutter

i've made this row of containers then used a gesture detector to detect tapping but it doesn't seem to be working here

i've tried Inkwell but nothing changed

**Edit: I've tried changeing the whole Buttons Row with a different widget (FlatButton) but nothing changed so the problem seems to be in the parent class but i don't know what is wrong with it 
Note: i couldn't post the whole parent class because my post will be mostly code**

this is a gist of the parent class 
https://gist.github.com/A-Siam/79435551b4c3463522e9dd08e44bd833

parent class

```dart
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  PageController pageController;
  List<bool> selected = [true, false, false];
  List<List<bool>> selectionCases = [
    [true, false, false],
    [false, true, false],
    [false, false, true]
  ];
  @override
  void initState() {
    pageController = PageController(viewportFraction: 1);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double padding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top + 50;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: BackGroundColor,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          CustomAppBar(
            padding: padding,
            color: AppBarColor,
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: padding),
            child: ButtonsRow(
              pageController: pageController,
              selected: selected,
            ),
          ),
// some code...
```

Buttons Row state

```dart
class _ButtonsRowState extends State<ButtonsRow> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              print("please help me");
            },
                      child: AnimatedContainer(
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
// some code...
```

what i want to achieve is creating this custom tab bar
[image]

Comment: Try using Inkwell instead of GestureDetector, it should work with animated widgets

Comment: I have tried this code and working fine, could you please show some more code?

Comment: Please update your question with the rest of the code as it is relevant.

Comment: @Ovidiu ok done

Comment: @ibhavikmakwana i've tried inkwell but nothing changed

Comment: try adding behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent, in GestureDetetor

Comment: I meant add the rest of the code of the `build` function of your `_ButtonsRowState` class. The full hierarchy of descendants of the `GestureDetector` is especially important.

Comment: @Ovidiu this is a gist of my complete code https://gist.github.com/A-Siam/b8bd3e2499091362f5db4676cd0f8002, my post won't be edited because it will be mostly code

Comment: That was useful - there is only one thing that is still missing - can you show the code of `DarkBackgroundText`? My guess so far is that your GestureDetector's child does not have a background (even Color.transparent would work, but you are using DarkBackgroundText and that might not have a background)

Comment: @Ovidiu it was a color constant however i have tried a different widget (FlatButton) but nothing changed i think the problem was in the parent widget https://gist.github.com/A-Siam/79435551b4c3463522e9dd08e44bd833, thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,` in your `GestureDetector`

Like below.

```
GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
  ...
)
```

Comment: unfortunately nothing changed